# Is setting the k8s GC HighThresholdPercent to 0 a bad idea?

Tags: kubernetes

Per the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#containers-images):

> Disk usage above the configured `HighThresholdPercent` value triggers garbage collection, which deletes images in order based on the last time they were used, starting with the oldest first. The kubelet deletes images until disk usage reaches the `LowThresholdPercent` value.

If this is set to 0, would that mean that garbage collection is always run?

What if it is set to 80, and 85% of the disk is being used by images that shouldn't be garbage collected? Will the GC just continuously run until it can cull it down to 80?

Comment: I think it should be `Yes` for both cases:
1. If you run containers, disk usage always will be great then 0. So process will not stops.
2. It will delete all old images, but not images that still `in work`. Due to this process will be also in progress, until achievement of LowThresholdPercent value.

Comment: I've tried to provide a relevant comment, but now I see that it cannot be done for particular data - it is not enough for good answer. For the 1st question:  `HighThresholdPercent` cannot be less then `LowThresholdPercent` (default is 80) and they cannot be equal. Now it is `0`. Can you improve your question description?
For the 2nd question: 80 is `HighThresholdPercent` or `LowThresholdPercent`? Because, as previously mentioned, default value for `LowThresholdPercent`  is 80. What values should be there?